# How to use blade template in slim php framework

Tags: php, laravel, slim, laravel-blade

I am using Slim 3 PHP framework. I know laravel 5.2.So I want to integrate Blade Template in my slim php framework.Can anyone suggest me best way to integrate blade template in slim framework using composer.What should I place in composer.json in require section????

Answer (score 3):

One way to use Laravel's components outside of Laravel is to look at [Torch](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch).

See their [view](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/tree/master/components/view) component for how to use Blade.

If you're not wedded to Blade, then look at [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org), as the Slim project maintains a component called [Twig-View](http://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View/) to integrate Twig into Slim.

Comment: I used Twig.Its working Thanks Allen.And one more thing Allen I want to ask you that I have used Illuminate's Paginator library in my Slim Framework. So in order to show pagination links in twig template I used {{ students->links() }} but it is not working.It is showing me code not showing me links

Comment: I believe you want `{{ students->links()|raw }}` to disable escaping

Comment: No it is not working at all. It throws an error "Unexpected token "operator" of value ">". ". Type: Twig_Error_Syntax

Comment: You cannot call an object's method within a Twig tag like that. Assign `links` to `$students->links()` in the PHP data array that you're going to render and then in the Twig template you can do `{{ links }}` or `{{ links|raw }}`

Comment: Sorry still not working. {% set links = students->links() %} {{ links }}. This code is also throwing same error in twig template.Is there any other way for displaying pagination's links???

Comment: You have to add it to the PHP array before calling render() - in the same place where you are assigning students to Twig.

Comment: Oh yeah now its working.Now I can get pagination link in my template.Here is my controller's code:$students = Student::paginate(10);
        $paginationLink = $students->links();
        return $this->view->render($response, 'students/list.twig', [
            'students' => Student::all(),
            'paginationLink' => $paginationLink
        ]);  @Rob Allen

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Laravel's blade and view outside the framework directly. Extracting those and making it work outside in another framework can be tiresome. You might want to check out these packages who do it for you and provide the functionality.

https://github.com/duncan3dc/blade

https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade

https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne

You can also try `Twig` which is a popular templating engine for PHP and the syntax is almost similar.

https://twig.sensiolabs.org/